# Формат вывода числа

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на php можно разделить части числа точками при выводе, т.е., например число 1234567890 вывести в виде 1.234.567.890

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это должно подойти, если вопрос о php --- [number_format](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php)