# Как группировать числа?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, css-animation

Есть форма ввода цены "от" и "до" когда человек вводит цифры
то они выглядят вот так: "10000" и "20000"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтоб их группировать по 3 вот так:
"10 000" и "20 000"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744725/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-input-ui-slider - Вот тут уже есть решение.

Comment: что значит "группировать по 3 вот так:"  о какой группировке речь ?   форматирование чисел ?

Comment: при вводе что они были по 3
"000 000 000"

Comment: Это называется number_format. в PHP есть такая функция, а для Javascript - сюда  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743911/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-number-format-%D0%B2-js

Comment: мне лучше на php, как называется функция в php?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Формат вывода числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/156589/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: Здравствуйте, для вашей цели предлагаю использовать библиотеку masked input. С ее помощью можно задавать маску для ввода. (Поддерживает регулярные выражения, хотя в вашем случае можно обойтись и без них)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в javaScript есть метод

```
number.toLocaleString()
```

он возвращает строку содержащую число в том виде который вам нужен